# Swift Stripe Integration

Tags: swift, cocoapods, stripe-payments

I installed the Stripe cocoapod into my project. Everything looks fine, but in my bridging header I'm getting file not found for Stripe.h: http://cl.ly/image/0h0Q3p0X3V3a.

Here's my pod http://cl.ly/image/043q1e1q2X1L

Has anyone seen this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's `import <Stripe/Stripe.h>`

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right. All the examples I've seen show it the other way. Thanks!